# Data Caching in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching

We store the location information in a table. Numbers of records are over four thousand. This table structure is self-recursive. In our web project, we use dropdownlist control to populate all these locations. We got performance slow problem. So googling about Caching, we consider to use Data Caching with Sql Dependency. However, not found yet a full-covered sample in .NET 2.0 and SQL Server 2005 or 2008. Please share me.

Comment: Before you start caching your data, have you checked where the performance issue is?

Comment: We're still finding where the issue is? Because at our office, loading time is around 3 sec. But at client side, it's over 7 sec.

Comment: another case - we use a third party control - multi-column drop down. At every post back, its datasource is auto nothing. so I code the 1st time from Database, the rest from viewState. here which way is better to performance issue?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two articles with full details with sample code on working with SqlDependency Caching using Sql Server 2005 and ASP.NET 2.0

1. [Article 1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mosessaur/sqlcachedependency01292006135138pm/sqlcachedependency.aspx)
2. [Article 2](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Using-the-ASP-NET-2-0-SQL-Server-Cache-Dependency.id-306459.html)